# How can I trigger an autoit python script on a windows device remotely?

Tags: python, windows, paramiko, autoit

I have an autoit python script saved on my windows PC, which carries out certain GUI operations. I need to trigger this script remotely from a linux device. I am using paramiko to establish an ssh connection with the windows PC and am trying to trigger the autoit python script on windows using exec_command(). 
When I check stdout.read(), I am only seeing the print statements written in the python script, but the GUI itself is not being launched.

Here is an illustration of what I am trying to achieve:

remote linux device --> trigger autoit python script --> script saved on Windows PC

```
import os
import paramiko 

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='10.209.80.96', username='administrator', password='Embe1mpls', 
allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False, banner_timeout=120)
ssh._transport.set_keepalive(60)
ssh.get_transport()

ssh.invoke_shell(width=200)

command="gui_simulator.py"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
stdout.read()
```

Here, gui_simulator.py is the autoit python script saved on my Windows PC.

What can I do to correct this?

Comment: Did you test any other commands? Try to run notepad.exe on that remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

Update:
The way I achieved this is by converting my autoit au3 scripts into .exe files and then calling those exe files in my selenium script i.e. gui_simulator.py

So, my au3 script consists of recorded actions and this is played by Selenium.

I had some limitations with Selenium and so I could not perform all the automation actions using Selenium alone.